# Python class members scanning - Why __bases__ recursive scan is required in get members?

Tags: python, introspection, base-class

I found the following function, but I have no idea why additional `__bases__` scan is required:

```
def getMembersWithBases(classType):
    members = set(dir(classType))
    # recursive bases scan
    for baseClassType in classType.__bases__:
        members.update(getMembersWithBases(baseClassType))
    return members
```

The following function is faster and gives same results - so why is the additional `__bases__` scan needed at al?

```
def getMembers(classType):
    members = set(dir(classType))
    return members
```

Some test code with both new- and old-style classes:

```
class Father(object):
    def testFather():
        pass

class Mother(object):
    def testMother():
        pass

class Child(Father, Mother):
    def testChild():
        pass

print type(Child)
print getMembers(Child) == getMembersWithBases(Child)                                             

class Father:
    def testFather():
        pass

class Mother:
    def testMother():
        pass

class Child(Father, Mother):
    def testChild():
        pass

print type(Child)
print getMembers(Child) == getMembersWithBases(Child)
```

Result:

```
<type 'type'>
True
<type 'classobj'>
True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the [`dir()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir), for classes, already includes all the classes listed in `__bases__`:

> If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases.

However, it is possible for a class to *override* that behaviour by specifying a `__dir__` method (via a metaclass, a classmethod is not enough):

> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called and must return the list of attributes.

When a `__dir__()` method is present, `__bases__` is not recursed over:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def spam(self): pass
... 
>>> class Bar(object):
...     def ham(self): pass
... 
>>> class CustomDirMetaclass(type):
...     def __dir__(cls):
...         return ['eggs']
... 
>>> class Baz(Foo, Bar):
...     __metaclass__ = CustomDirMetaclass
...     def eggs(self): pass
... 
>>> dir(Baz)
['eggs']
>>> getMembers(Baz)
set(['eggs'])
>>> getMembersWithBases(Baz)
set(['__module__', '__getattribute__', 'eggs', '__reduce__', '__subclasshook__', '__dict__', '__sizeof__', '__weakref__', '__init__', 'ham', '__setattr__', '__reduce_ex__', '__new__', 'spam', '__format__', '__class__', '__doc__', '__delattr__', '__repr__', '__hash__', '__str__'])
```

Thus, the explicit recursion over `__bases__` in the `getMembersWithBases()` class method could be an attempt at bypassing any custom `__dir__()` implementations.

Otherwise, the recursion over `__bases__` is completely redundant.

In my personal opinion, the recursion over `__bases__` is redundant even *if* there *are* `__dir__()` methods present in the class hierarchy. In such cases, the `__dir__()` method override is at fault as *that* method should recurse over the classes listed in `__bases__` to correctly mimic the behaviour of the `dir()` function.

To be honest, I suspect that the author of the function that you found was not aware of the recursive nature of `dir()`, and added the `__bases__` recursion needlesly, not as a means to bypass custom `__dir__()` methods.

Comment: @KayZhu: Indeed, a metaclass could specify a custom `__bases__` attribute, at which point `dir()` would not be able to recurse over the hierarchy *either*. In my opinion, any `__dir__` implementation that doesn't itself recurse over `__bases__` is broken, btw.

Comment: It looks in that specific case that scanning bases is redundant in the most cases since and it is not right pattern to follow bad pattern with \_\_bases\_\_ workaround. Maybe there is other usage?

Comment: @Chameleon: Not that I am aware of, I'd say the recursion over `__bases__` is *always* going to be redundant, and any problems with `__dir__()` methods should be fixed in those methods, not by bypassing them.

Comment: The best is to fix errors with \_\_dir\_\_() in \_\_dir\_\_() better than produce strange workarounds.